# TDBGrid where is the SQL WHERE condition?

Tags: sql, delphi

I am working on an already started Delphi project where there is a `TDBGrid`. The grid seems to be filled by a `TADOTable` that refer to a Bill table in the dataset.

It display a bill by `PkBill`. I can't seem to find **where in the design or in code someone told to load only for this pk.**

I need to load multiples Pk at the same time. I'm used to create programmatically a TADOQuery, create a connection, write my SQL code, then do what I want with the result. With those objects/controls, I just don't know where to do that.

Thanks for the help and clarity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `TADOTable.MasterSource` to see if it's in the Master-Detail relationship.
Or you could check `TADOTable.Filtered` and `TADOTable.Filter` to see if it's being filtered by `PkBill`.

Comment: The `ADOTable Filter` is empty, `Filtered` is True, and the MasterSource` is empty.

Comment: Oh! Find that the `ADOTable.Filter = VariablePk` . Can I add multiples pk to this filter?

Comment: Yes. Something like `Name = 'PkBill' or Name = 'PkBob'`

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try and come back to you if it resolve my problem =)

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much =) Didn't know about this `filter` property! ^o^

Comment: Note that there is also an [OnFilterRecord](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnFilterRecord) event handler that can be used for filtering